# ajax no show data on web host (Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null)

Tags: php, ajax

Jquery work fine on localhost but when I move it to web host this part not work
I check for MIME Type In Cpanel and try to change "url" to 'nameofproject/application/controllers/app/update_chat' same its work on localhost but not on web server

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        show_chat_main();
        
setInterval(show_chat_main, 1000);

function show_chat_main() {
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                url   : '<?php echo site_url('app/update_chat')?>',
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
var jsString= '<?=$this->session->userdata('user_id');?>';

                        if (data[i].user_id == jsString && data[i].ch_gr_id == 0) {
                        html += '<li class="clearfix">'+
                                '<div class="message my-message" style="border: 1px solid #a927f9 !important;"><p class="rounded-circle float-end">'+data[i].user_name+'</p>'+
                                '<div class="message-data"><span class="message-data-time">'+data[i].created_at+'</span>'+
                                '</div><hr style="color: #a927f9;"><p>'+data[i].message+'</p></div>'+
                                '</li>';
                            } else if (data[i].user_id != jsString && data[i].ch_gr_id == 0) {
                        html += '<li class="clearfix">'+
                                '<div class="message other-message pull-right" style="border: 1px solid #7366ff !important;"><p class="rounded-circle float-end">'+data[i].user_name+'</p>'+
                                '<div class="message-data"><span class="message-data-time">'+data[i].created_at+'</span>'+
                                '</div><hr style="color: #7366ff;"><p>'+data[i].message+'</p></div>'+
                                '</li>';
                            }
                    }
                    $('#show_data').html(html);
                }
            });
}
    });
 
</script>
```

in browser this error

```
   Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much
I found where was the problem its In DataType
this is how it look now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        show_chat_main();
        
setInterval(show_chat_main, 1000);

function show_chat_main() {
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'post',
                url   : '<?=base_url('index.php/app/update_chat'); ?>',
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
var jsString= '<?=$this->session->userdata('user_id');?>';

                        if (data[i].user_id == jsString && data[i].ch_gr_id == 0) {
                        html += '<li class="clearfix">'+
                                '<div class="message my-message" style="border: 1px solid #a927f9 !important;"><p class="rounded-circle float-end">'+data[i].user_name+'</p>'+
                                '<div class="message-data"><span class="message-data-time">'+data[i].created_at+'</span>'+
                                '</div><hr style="color: #a927f9;"><p>'+data[i].message+'</p></div>'+
                                '</li>';
                            } else if (data[i].user_id != jsString && data[i].ch_gr_id == 0) {
                        html += '<li class="clearfix">'+
                                '<div class="message other-message pull-right" style="border: 1px solid #7366ff !important;"><p class="rounded-circle float-end">'+data[i].user_name+'</p>'+
                                '<div class="message-data"><span class="message-data-time">'+data[i].created_at+'</span>'+
                                '</div><hr style="color: #7366ff;"><p>'+data[i].message+'</p></div>'+
                                '</li>';
                            }
                    }
                    $('#show_data').html(html);
                }
            });
}
    });
 
</script>
```